# Passing argument with TestNG DataProvider parallel = true from @Test to Listeners

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have DataProvider generating some data and feed it to my @Test

```js
@DataProvider(name = "dp", parallel = true)
public Object[][] getBrowser(Method m) {

  Iterator < String > iterator = Constants.browsers.iterator();
  String browser = null;
  Object[][] data = new Object[2][1];

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
      browser = iterator.next();
      data[i][0] = browser;
    }
  }

  return data;

}
```

Constants.browsers would look like this

```
public static final List<String> browsers = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList("Chrome","Edge"));
```

Basically just generating 2 data "Chrome" and "Edge" and then feed it to my @Test , which looks like this

```js
@Test(dataProviderClass = TestUtilities.class, dataProvider = "dp")
public void testing(String browser, ITestContext context) throws InterruptedException {

  ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
  result.getMethod().setDescription(browser);

  context.setAttribute("browser", browser);

  initiate(browser, Constants.baseURL); //Instantiate Chrome or Edge WebDriver and go to the URL

  //  Do the testing

  closeBrowser();
}
```

I have setup TestNG listeners

```js
public class myListeners extends TestBase implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

    String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();

    String browser = result.getMethod().getDescription();
    log.debug("ITestResult --> BROWSER is " + browser);

  }



  @Override
  public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {

    String usedBrowser = null;
    usedBrowser = (String) context.getAttribute("browser");
    log.debug("ITestContext --> Used Browser  : " + usedBrowser);

  }
}
```

Since `@DataProvider(name = "dp", parallel = true)` , there will be 2 threads running at the same time. Chrome browser and Edge browser. I can see both of them starts at the same time and do some testing. Once the test finishes , both browsers quit().

I run it from my testng.xml which looks like this

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="My Test Suite" parallel="tests">

  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="myListeners.myListeners"></listener>
  </listeners>

  <test name="myTest" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="testCases.testing" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

My issue is the listeners only print one of the thread.
Sometimes it prints

`18:38:02.110 DEBUG TestBase -ITestResult --> BROWSER is Chrome`

`18:38:04.190 DEBUG TestBase -ITestContext --> Used Browser  : Chrome`

Sometimes it prints

`18:38:02.110 DEBUG TestBase -ITestResult --> BROWSER is Edge`

`18:38:04.190 DEBUG TestBase -ITestContext --> Used Browser  : Edge`

My expectation is that both parameters can be printed (logged) , like this (don't worry about the timestamp)

`18:38:02.110 DEBUG TestBase -ITestResult --> BROWSER is Chrome`

`18:38:02.110 DEBUG TestBase -ITestResult --> BROWSER is Edge`

`18:38:04.190 DEBUG TestBase -ITestContext --> Used Browser  : Chrome`

`18:38:04.190 DEBUG TestBase -ITestContext --> Used Browser  : Edge`

How can I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the attribute as you are setting in ITestContext for ITestResult

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = TestUtilities.class, dataProvider = "dp")
public void testing(String browser, ITestContext context) throws InterruptedException {

  ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
  // Changes here 
  result.setAttribute("browser", browser);

  context.setAttribute("browser", browser);

  initiate(browser, Constants.baseURL); //Instantiate Chrome or Edge WebDriver and go to the URL

  //  Do the testing

  closeBrowser();
}
```

---

```
@Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

    String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();

    //String browser = result.getMethod().getDescription();
  // changes here
    log.debug("ITestResult --> BROWSER is " + (String) result.getAttribute("browser"));

  }
```

Below method will be executed only once

```
  /**
   * Invoked after all the test methods belonging to the classes inside the <test> 
   tag have run
   * and all their Configuration methods have been called.
   *
   * @param context The test context
   */

    @Override
      public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    
        String usedBrowser = null;
        usedBrowser = (String) context.getAttribute("browser");
        log.debug("ITestContext --> Used Browser  : " + usedBrowser);
    
      }
```

You will get output - something like this

```
DEBUG TestBase -ITestResult --> BROWSER is Chrome

DEBUG TestBase -ITestResult --> BROWSER is Edge

DEBUG TestBase -ITestContext --> Used Browser  : Edge --- Note this--
```

On Finish will execute only once

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying your suggestion, I still see the same issue as before. I only see ITestResult being printed once only.  Quick question, OnFinish will be executed once only, meaning the last executed thread will overwrite the previous thread that finishes earlier?   Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You are setting the context.setAttribute("browser", browser) in ITestContext So it will be overridden . One of test may be failing so you are seeing the issue "only see ITestResult being printed once only" Overide onTestFailure,onTestSkipped as well

Comment: The test doesn't do anything actually. It only starts Chrome and Edge browsers at the same time , and then go to www.google.com. That's it. No assertion or other method to check anything. After that, just call quit(). When I execute the code, I can see those browsers start at the same time, go to google.com, and then close the browser.

Comment: My bad. Actually ITestResult was printed twice in the console, but the first one comes at the top of the log stack , the second one comes at the very last at the bottom. Only after I check the .log file , I can see both of them are printed in the log file in a good order.  Thanks a lot for your help Rahul :)